# How to get the value of variable in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I'm using the following code to get the value of variable "one" in jQuery

```
var one=1;
$('td:nth-child(one)')
```

But "one" is taken as a string not as a variable. How to get the value of the variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
var one=1;
$('td:nth-child(' + one + ')');
```

Answer (score 3):

Same as javascript,

```
var one=1;
$('td:nth-child(' + one +')')
```

Answer (score 2):

Like normal string concatenation in JavaScript:

```
var one=1;
$('td:nth-child(' + one + ')')
```